# PHP FTP transfer

Tags: php, ftp, transfer

I have files that are automatically uploaded onto a server from mobile phones, and I need to automatically transfer these files from the server to another server using PHP.

Could someone please explain how I would do this?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Where is the PHP running? Does the network permit FTP between the 2 locations? In the direction you want? What have you tried and why isn't it working?

Comment: Is your environment constraint to use a ftp server or can you choose another protocol as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has FTP functionality built in with [FTP wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php):

> Allows read access to existing files and creation of new files via FTP. If the server does not support passive mode ftp, the connection will fail.

This means you can use FTP like any other file - an extremely simple example:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('some/other/file.txt');
$fname = "ftp://name:yourpassword@127.55.41.10:21/some/path/filename.txt";
file_put_contents($fname,$data);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Piskvor, I'll have a go at doing this. Does this PHP file need to be on the receiving server or the sending server?

Comment: This file needs to be on the sending server. The receiving Server needs to have a ftp server running.

Comment: @Daniel H: The one you're connecting *from*; the receiving server only needs to have a running FTP server.